# Restoring Nexus 4 to Factory image

Tags: ubuntu-touch, data-recovery, nexus-4

I have been attempting to restore the Factory image of 4.2.1 through the terminal in Ubuntu, but the whole progress halts when I try to use the `./flash-all.sh` commands. It sits in the "waiting for device" screen and goes nowhere. I can't help to think that I am missing something. I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: close the thread. It went through after an hour.

Comment: You can delete it yourself can't you?  There should be a delete button under the tags.

Answer (score 0):

First, try running it as root. "sudo ./flash-all.sh". If you're going back to 4.2.1 from a 4.2.2 version, you may need to connect to your phone using adb and add your computer as one that is allowed to connect to it. 4.2.2 has a new feature that allows you to restrict which machines can connect for debug, etc. (try sudo first though)